# How to get application properties as java.util.Properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am developing a standalone spring boot application where we are using custom library for DB connection and related operation. This library can be initialized two way.

We can either

- Pass .properties file from File system or from class path properties file into our db config class
- We can pass properties object (java.util.properties)

I want to make use of spring properties feature (with active profile) so I'm going with second approach.

I tried to get all the loaded properties (based on active profile I set) using the below code :

```
@Component
public class ConfigProperties {
    
    private final Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    public ConfigProperties(Environment environment) {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    public Properties getAllProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        for (String propertyName : environment.getPropertySources().iterator().next().getPropertyNames()) {
            properties.setProperty(propertyName, environment.getProperty(propertyName));
        }
        return properties;
    }
}
```

I got the above idea from internet. But `getPropertySources()` is undefined in `Environment` class. I searched for other ways to get this achieved, but found nothing working.

Comment: It is part of `ConfigurableEnvironment`. However this feels like a bad idea and I doubt you want all properties just a subset that is needed for the datasource. Just get them from the `Environment` and pass them the a `Properties` object.